# How to add videos in jQuery Slideshow Maker

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to embedded a slider maker in my application , then I found https://www.slider-maker.com , this is fine for me , but I want to add both videos and images in a slideshow

So  is it possible to add videos also ?

Comment: Could you put your slider code here which you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Slider Maker

I'll work on your video slideshow feature, you'll be able to add any video (youtube, vimeo, ...) with just a link to video url. Usual parameters will be available : show / hide controls, autoplay, ...

Can you please contact me at https://www.miglisoft.com/#contact ?

I'll tell you when new [Slider Maker](https://www.slider-maker.com/) version is available (should be in 1 or 2 days)

EDIT : New version with video is ok now (and other improvements).

Live example here : https://www.slider-maker.com/slidermaker/demo-files/slideshows/beatles-video-slideshow.php